What is the correct usage of InterlockedCompareExchange for optimistic synchronization to avoid the new C28112 warning in MSVC?
I've written optimistic thread-synchronization routines lots of times before, but today, the pattern that I've used for years now generates a warning in recent versions of VC++ (using VS 2022, v17.9.5):
static volatile int32_t _value;

...

void UpdateValueAtomically(...)
{
    int32_t oldValue, newValue;

    do {
        oldValue = _value;
        newValue = /* ... calculate newValue from oldValue ... */ ;

    } while (InterlockedCompareExchange(&_value, newValue, oldValue) != oldValue);
}

In VC++, this now generates warning C28112 on the read of oldValue = _value, complaining that _value ought to be used only with Interlocked*() APIs.  There is, of course, no InterlockedRead(), but oldValue = InterlockedCompareExchange(&_value, 0, 0) could be used as an ugly equivalent; but I'm not convinced it's necessary.
Is VC++ correct in telling me there's an issue with the existing code that I've never noticed before?  Is there a race condition here I've always missed until now?  Or is VC++ warning about a problem that isn't actually there?

Is it possible to use std::atomic<int32_t>  instead of volatile int32_t? So you would not have to write the function UpdateValueAtomically that complicated ?

@wrongite There is no std::atomic<int32_t> in C.

Per C++11 17.6.4.3.2 Global names:  "Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace."  static volatile int32_t _value; conflicts with that.

Sorry I thought it is c++, how about oldValue = InterlockedOr(&_value, 0) ?

here of course no race condition

you can if want use EXTERN_C int __iso_volatile_load32( const volatile int *); and  oldValue = __iso_volatile_load32((const volatile int*)&_value);

@wrongite That's not fundamentally any better than my InterlockedCmpXchg() with zeros. The question is whether there's something actually wrong with the naked load of the volatile int, or if MSVC is wrong to be complaining about it.

@AndrewHenle This is not a question about naming, and not a question about C++. It's a question about a specific warning generated by Microsoft's C compiler, which is confusingly named "Visual C++."

@RbMm __iso_volatile_load32() is only supported on MSVC for ARM, not on x86.

@SeanWerkema - i build it on x64 and all ok. code compiled and run. so really it supported on x64 too (not check x86). and with optimization it simply generate the same instruction value = __iso_volatile_load32((const volatile __int32*)&_value); equal to value = _value; look in intrin0.inl.h this function declared with __MACHINE macro wich mean it for any platform

This may be a case where the use of #pragma warning(suppress, 28112) is called for. The page at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c28112?view=msvc-170 simply says that access via non-Interlocked* functions is allowed but needs to be examined.

i only not sure are use __iso_volatile_load32 supress warning, because i not got it and without this intrinsic

unfortunatelly no, value = __iso_volatile_load32((const volatile __int32*)&_value); anyway got warning C28112. despite it ok and for x86/x64 too

@IInspectable: The standard C equivalent (in C17) is _Atomic int32_t _value; atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&_value, &old_value, new_value); after #include <stdatomic.h>.  Does MSVC support that?

@NateEldredge C11 atomics were introduced about 1.5 years ago. I fear that doesn't help answer the question. It merely shifts the issue from understanding Windows' memory model to understanding C's. I don't understand either sufficiently well to propose an answer.

@IInspectable: With C11 atomics the answer is straightforward and well defined: any read of an _Atomic variable is atomic and does not cause a data race (and you can use atomic_load_explicit to dispense with unnecessary memory barriers).  I am not sure if Windows ever defined its memory model precisely enough to be able to answer formally, but probably in practice a read of a volatile variable is also atomic.

@NateEldredge read of a volatile variable is also atomic. - volatile and atomic 2 absolute unrelated things. volatile only mean drop any compiler optimization and always read variable as is. but if int (32bit) will be not aligned on 4*x address, even simply it read can be not atomic. however if it aligned as need - any read will be atomic


warning C28112: A variable (_value) which is accessed via an
Interlocked function must always be accessed via an Interlocked
function

this is wrong. interlocked have sense only for read–modify–write operations. but not for read only or write only. for this (read only, write only) need only atomic access. so code is correct and warning is wrong here. however this also is stated:

Although certain ordinary assignments, accesses, and comparisons to variables that are used by the Interlocked routines can be safely
accessed by using a different function, the risk is great enough to
justify examining each instance.

also instead declare variable as volatile, you can remove volatile and use __iso_volatile_load/store intrinsics for read this variable.

You can use the __iso_volatile_load8/16/32/64 and __iso_volatile_store8/16/32/64 intrinsics to explicitly perform memory accesses that aren't subject to compiler optimizations. The compiler
can't remove, synthetize, or change the relative order of these
operations, but it doesn't generate implicit hardware memory barriers.
Therefore, the hardware may still reorder the observable memory
accesses across multiple threads. More precisely, these intrinsics are
equivalent to the following expressions as compiled under
/volatile:iso.

int a = __iso_volatile_load32(p);    // equivalent to: int a = *(const volatile __int32*)p;
__iso_volatile_store32(p, a);        // equivalent to: *(volatile __int32*)p = a;

despite it marked as for ARM only, in documentation, it work on x64/x86 too, and you can found it declaration in intrin0.inl.h
__MACHINE(__int32 __iso_volatile_load32(const volatile __int32 *))

note that __MACHINE macro is used, not __MACHINEARM64 or __MACHINEARM_ARM64
** __MACHINE              : everything

so code can be next:
//#include <intrin0.inl.h>
EXTERN_C __int32 __iso_volatile_load32(const volatile __int32*);

static long _value;

long calculate(long);

void UpdateValueAtomically()
{
    long OldValue, value = __iso_volatile_load32((const volatile __int32*)&_value);

    do {
        value = InterlockedCompareExchangeNoFence(
            &_value, calculate(value), OldValue = value);

    } while (value != OldValue);
}

also note different with your loop - you access _value 2 time in loop:

oldValue = _value;
InterlockedCompareExchange(&_value, newValue, oldValue)

I read _value once before loop, and then access _value only 1 time in loop, and then use value returmed from InterlockedCompareExchange.

also possible next implementation, without warning:
void UpdateValueAtomically()
{
    long OldValue, value = 0;

    do {
        value = InterlockedCompareExchangeNoFence(
            &_value, calculate(value), OldValue = value);

    } while (value != OldValue);
}

here we access _value only via InterlockedCompareExchange. we not read it once before loop ( __iso_volatile_load32((const volatile __int32*)&_value) ) but assume some current value ( value = 0). if this is not true ( _value != 0 ) at this time, we simply again execute InterlockedCompareExchange with already actual value, from previous try

It's a good answer, but the part that's really missing is a direct answer to the question, "If MSVC thinks this code is wrong, what code does Microsoft recommend instead?" All of your answers work around the problem, but none of them are guaranteed not to raise new warnings in the future. Microsoft's recommended pattern — whatever it might be — presumably would have an implicit guarantee that it wouldn't raise future warnings.

@SeanWerkema - you can use last code snipet, if want. where we access _value only via  InterlockedCompareExchange. this is optimized code compare your original - when you 2 access _value in loop. we assume 0 as initial value - but can use here any. really in most case variable which is accessed via an Interlocked function must always be accessed via an Interlocked function. usual we need only add/sub/and/or logic and exist Interlocked for this. only if you need more complex logic for RMW operation, you need first read _value before loop. or assume some value.

@SeanWerkema and you not need volatile keyword. even not need this __iso_volatile_load32, if you access value only inside UpdateValueAtomically and return some value from this function for use (you dont do this, so need access _value somewhere else). the InterlockedCompareExchange by self create memory barier for compiler and hardware.

@SeanWerkema - "If MSVC thinks this code is wrong, what code does Microsoft recommend instead?" MSVC not 100% think this, only warn. as example - reference counting variable. we access it only via AddRef/Release with InterlockedIncrement/InterlockedDecrement and use result of this api (dec only) for delete when value became 0. but never direct access, only init to 1. this is clasasic logic and usually only it used. but assume more complex logic - need v++ in case v > 0 and no change if v == 0. no such Interlocked and you need InterlockedCompareExchange in loop, as you do. not usual, but ok
